# Somar resultado de uma coluna e exibir

Tags: php

tudo bom? Estou fazendo um inserção no banco de dados em um determinada coluna. Entretanto, quando eu tento usar a função WHILE para me exibir o resultado, ao invés dele somar ele me trás todos os resultados. Entretanto, eu quero somar o resultado e exibir a soma final. Veja abaixo o código que estou utilizando.

```
<?php 

            $Fundos = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM saldo WHERE login = '$usuario'");

            while($exibeFundos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Fundos)){

            $valor = $exibeFundos['valorSaldoAtivo'] + $exibeFundos['valorSaldoAtivo'];
?>
            <?=$valor; ?>

            <?php }      ?>
```

Comment: "*fazendo um inserção no banco*", inserção ou está apenas selecionando?

Answer (score -1):

Eu consegui resolve. obrigado @Rodolfo Silva, mas eu consegui vlw.

```
<?php 

            $Fundos = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM saldo WHERE login = '$usuario'");

                        $valor = 0;

            while($exibeFundos = mysqli_fetch_array($Fundos)){

            $valor = $valor + $exibeFundos['valorSaldoAtivo'];
 }  
    ?>

 <?=$valor?>
```

Comment: Não há motivos para fazer isso no PHP. No SQL você pode fazer `SELECT SUM(valorSaldoAtivo) as total` e retornar o resultado de uma vez.

Comment: oxe, não sabia....